# char** : Parse the entire memory properly

Tags: c, parsing, char, malloc, file-descriptor

Im am trying to get some words from a txt file and store them into a char** . Although I think my array allocates corectly room for 100 words , my last one fails to be printed in a human-readable way.Also,if you look carefully there are 4 characters that are being printed (so this indicates that the correct size of memory refers to the lenght of the word,which is 4). Can you please point out for what am I missing ? I am running in linux Ubuntu 20.04 (VirtualBox).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#define N 100
#define STRLIM 60

char** cat;
int fd;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   int i;
  
    
    cat=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*N);
    fd=open("dictionary.txt",O_RDONLY); 
    if(fd==-1){
        printf("fd error %d" , fd);
        perror("Error:");        
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        cat[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLIM);
       
        read(fd,cat[i],40);
        printf("%s", cat[i]);
    }
    printf("the value of i is: %d",i);
   
    
    return 0;
}//end of main
```

PS: I am getting a warning that which goes like this :
v1.c:25:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘read’; did you mean ‘fread’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Is it really necessary for "read" to have an unsigned int as a third arguement?

The words of the "dictionary.txt" are these (there a hundred words down bellow)  :

```
shocking
boundary
post
dapper
zoom
bashful
damaging
sore
unadvised
fresh
birthday
wrathful
hook
nose
wonder
doubt
important
synonymous
bell
dare
selective
raspy
unused
heavy
wiggly
land
coal
humorous
humdrum
plausible
languid
depressed
imminent
helpless
parsimonious
verse
deep
tricky
window
sedate
torpid
earsplitting
protect
breath
drawer
pear
bomb
drum
can
superficial
crook
stimulating
majestic
innocent
steep
robin
weak
tumble
geese
bulb
channel
frantic
obtain
shave
nerve
boiling
picture
sand
measly
tasteful
steadfast
hallowed
rabid
fax
aspiring
utter
wave
confused
zephyr
absent
lamentable
idea
oatmeal
comfortable
cars
reduce
colossal
heat
lettuce
simple
homeless
decision
cellar
ruthless
time
railway
possible
silly
chance
food
```

Comment: `read(fd,cat[i],40);` ? You certainly not want to read 40 bytes everytime

Comment: ' cat=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*N);'  allocates space for N chars, not N char*

Comment: Martin thanks for telling me that was just a typo but you get the idea.Also I included that unistd.h as BlueDiary told me , and I also figured out after all that "read" function is kind of flexible and does not demand an unsigned int as its third arguement.Really greatful for your help.

Comment: Is there any kind of extension (VsCode) that fills in for you automatically what libraries to include if you want to use a fucntion that you have already written in your code ? And also , it might be a little too much to ask for but ,what was causing the printing problem at firtst place ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, wasn't able to add a comment...
you won't get a warning if you include unistd.h.
I don't know why you want to use the malloc function in this code (maybe for another part of the code).
It is better to have a buffer and do something like this:

```
char buffer[STRLIM];
int x;
while ((x = read(fd, buffer, STRLIM)) > 0) {
    write(1, buffer, x);
}
```

where x is the number of bytes that the read function was able to read from the file, and then we write x bytes to the output.